# Glass material with darker areas Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, glass

I'm modelling a nutella pot, however I have a rendering problem.
[image]

As you can see I have a dark spot around the glass pot, my shading render is very simple though :

[image]

Also, I made the nutella model and the pot to intersect as saw in the Blender Guru donut tutorial series so there are no arctefacts. I tried to play with Light Paths values but it didn't changed a thing.
I'm clueless here.

**Edit**

Here is the .blend file :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1raZvaCW-5wCaXbtoebrNK1KYopJt6opm

Comment: Hello :). This can have multiple reasons, could you [share your .blend file?](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). To prevent guessing :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recreated your scene, and after examining the renders, it seems that the HDRI/Scene that you've created for lighting is causing the dark spots;

[image]

Try using another HDRI, or rotating the view, to see what I mean. I'm using this HDRI;

[image]

Which can be found in various resolutions here;

https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?c=indoor&h=lebombo

### Edit:

I see. Forgive me, I don't eat gnutella, and so our bottles were totally different. While mine was perfectly round, yours has a very unique (and by the way nicely modeled) shape;

[image]

Your specific issue is the table (you didn't pack the images, so this is going to look a bit odd);

[image]

[image]

If I change the table to a darker color, you see that the issue with your bottle isn't dark parts, it's an especially light table, contrasting against a dark background;

[image]

I bet you could replicate these results in real life with a bottle of gnutella and a table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My render was using 3 suns to light the scene. I try to setup an HDRI background, it did change a bit, and I think it that my lighting setup isn't optimized. It can also be the nutella material as I try to move it around and it has some reflections on it.

Comment: If you'd like to share the file, I can examine it further.

Comment: I added to a link to the main post. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer based on that file. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me and to process through this ! Really that's a idiot issue haha, I see now.

Comment: Haha, don't feel bad, reflection/refraction is tough to troubleshoot :)