# Object becomes dark with mesh glitches after rendering as a glass using Cycles

Tags: materials, lighting, glass

I'm a beginner in Blender and I was trying to do a glass bottle. The problem is that when I render the object, the glass become dark in it's bottom side, as for the image:

[image: These are the Shader setting that I'm using]

I've tried a variety of things to try and fix this problem such as:

- Change the Shader to Glass BSDF
- Change the values in Max Bounces
- Recalculate Normals
- Change the HDR since I was using a darker one
- And other things that I saw in tutorials and other questions here

But I have not succeded in any of this alternatives.

My object is currently using the following modifiers

- Solidify with 0.5 Thickness
- Subdivision Surface with default values
- Fluid since the object will be an effector for fluids inside it

I'm using Blender in version 3.4.1

Comment: Are you talking about the reflection of the HDRI?

Comment: Hi Vagabonk! Actually no, I was just under the impression that a dark HDR would result in a dark light shining through the bottle, I dont know if this makes sense but I thought about it while troubleshooting when I found this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172384/glass-material-with-darker-areas-cycles